# Starling GAF animation - FPS change

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

I am working on a project which run on 40 FPS but, I have some GAF animation that the animator worked on 24 FPS.

When I play the animation they run really fast (40 FPS).
Is there any way to run the GAF animation on the current FPS that they were made in?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the framerate when playing it then change it back when done:

```
stage.frameRate = 24;
```